# Efficent way to loop through Pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a population model featuring education.
I start with initial picture of the population that gives the number of people for each age group (0 to 95), and each level of education (0 - No education, to 6 - University).

This picture is treated as a column of a dataframe, that will iteratively be populated for each new year as a forecast.
In order to be populated there will be assumptions or things such as mortality rate of each age group, enrollment rates and success rates of each education level and so on.

The way I solved the problem is by adding a new column and iterate through the rows by using the value for age-1 from the previous year in order to compute the new value (eg. number of males with age 5 is the number of males with age 4 at year-1 less the ones that died)

The problem with this solution is that iterating through pandas dataframe rows using for loops and .loc is very inefficient and it takes a lot of time to compute the forecast

```
       def add_year_temp(pop_table,time,
         old_year,new_year,
         enrollment_rate_primary,
         success_rate_primary,
         enrollment_rate_1st_cycle,
         success_rate_1st_cycle,
         enrollment_rate_2nd_cycle,
         success_rate_2nd_cycle,
         enrollment_rate_3rd_cycle,
         success_rate_3rd_cycle,
         enrollment_rate_university,
         success_rate_university,
         mortality_rate_0_1,
         mortality_rate_2_14,
         mortality_rate_15_64,
         mortality_rate_65,
         mortality_mf_ratio,
         enrollment_mf_ratio,
         success_mf_ratio):  

temp_table = pop_table
temp_table['year_ts'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_table[time])
temp_table['lag']= temp_table.groupby(['sex','schooling'])[old_year].shift(+1)
temp_table = temp_table.fillna(0)

for age in temp_table['age'].unique():
    for sex in temp_table['sex'].unique():

        mortality_mf_ratio_temp = 1
        enrollment_mf_ratio_temp = 1
        success_mf_ratio_temp = 1

        if sex == 'F':
            mortality_mf_ratio_temp = mortality_mf_ratio
            enrollment_mf_ratio_temp = enrollment_mf_ratio
            success_mf_ratio_temp = success_mf_ratio

        if   age <= 1:
            for schooling in [0]:

                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)]['lag']) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_0_1 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp)                         
        elif   1 < age <= 5:
            for schooling in [0]:

                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)]['lag']) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_2_14 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp)
```

## a lot of lines later you can see how for example I define the people that finish high-school and enter university...

```
        elif  15 < age <= 17:
            for schooling in [0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4]:
                temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                               & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                               & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==age-1) \
                               & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                               & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)][old_year]) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp)
        elif age == 18:
            for schooling in [0 ,1 ,2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if schooling == 0:
                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)]['lag']) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp) 
                elif schooling == 1:
                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==(age-1)) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)][old_year]) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp) 
                elif schooling == 2:
                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==(age-1)) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)][old_year]) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp)
                elif schooling == 3:
                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==(age-1)) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)][old_year]) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp)
                elif schooling == 4:
                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==(age-1)) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling)][old_year]) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 *  mortality_mf_ratio_temp) \
                    * (1 - enrollment_rate_3rd_cycle * enrollment_mf_ratio_temp \
                    * success_rate_3rd_cycle * success_mf_ratio_temp) 
                elif schooling == 5:
                    temp_table.loc[(temp_table['age']==age) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling),'lag'] = \
                    float(temp_table[(temp_table['age']==(age-1)) \
                                   & (temp_table['sex']== sex) \
                                   & (temp_table['schooling']== schooling-1)][old_year]) \
                    * (1 - mortality_rate_15_64 * mortality_mf_ratio_temp) \
                    * (enrollment_rate_3rd_cycle * enrollment_mf_ratio_temp \
                    * success_rate_3rd_cycle * success_mf_ratio_temp)
```

## And this continues for all age groups

As I said, it does work, but this is neither elegant nor fast...

Comment: you really dont need a loop for this sort of thing. you can create a function and use lambda to push it in.

Comment: Create a function and use `apply` on the dataframe along with the function name
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: define a function, which take rows value as input, calculate and return which `lag` value corresponding to that. Using pandas's `apply` on this function on your table. Using loop here is both not efficient and really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```py
temp_table['mortality_mf_ratio'] = temp_table.apply(lambda row: some_function_per_row(row), axis=1)
```

Or you could use `np.where` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```py
temp_table['mortality_mf_ratio'] = np.where(temp_table['sex'] == 'F', 1, 0)
```